# Highlight word on backspace and delete after second backspace

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<html>

  <body>
    <div id="textareaId" contenteditable="true">
      Hello there
    </div>
    <button onclick=selectText(0,4)>Click to select</button>
    <button onclick=deleteSelectedText()>Click to delete </button>
    <script>
    // Assuming 'textareaId' is the ID of your contenteditable div
    const contenteditableDiv = document.getElementById('textareaId');

    // Function to select a range of text within a contenteditable div
    function selectText(start, end) {

      const range = document.createRange();
      range.setStart(contenteditableDiv.firstChild, start);
      range.setEnd(contenteditableDiv.firstChild, end);

      const selection = window.getSelection();
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
    }

    // Function to delete the currently selected text
    function deleteSelectedText() {
      const selection = window.getSelection();
      if (!selection.isCollapsed) {
        selection.deleteFromDocument();
      }
    }

    // Add an event listener to the contenteditable div
    contenteditableDiv.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      if (event.key === '<' || event.key === 'Delete') {
        selectText(0, 5);
      }
      if (event.key === 'Backspace' || event.key === 'Delete') {
        deleteSelectedText();
      }
    });

// Example usage: select and delete text from 10th to 20th character`your text`


  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The selected word seems to be getting deleted on the first backspace. how do I change the function to highlight it first on backspace and then on second, delete it fully. I figured the highlighted area is just replace immediately on keydown so needs a different logic.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you would need to add `event.preventDefault();` before calling `deleteSelectedText();`

If not, your code firstly select the text, but then the default behavior kicks in and erases it.

Edit: just to be sure, you could also add `event.stopPropagation()` and `return false;` after `deleteSelectedText();`

```
// Add an event listener to the contenteditable div
contenteditableDiv.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.key === 'Backspace' || event.key === 'Delete') {
    event.preventDefault();

    const selection = window.getSelection();
    if (selection.isCollapsed) {
      deleteSelectedText();
    } else {
      selectText(0, 5);
    }
    
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight on e.preventdefault. I modified the code a little bit , added a variable to keep track of the backspace and unbinded the prevent.default on second press. (also the '<' should actually have been 'Backspace') !

Comment: @anirudh-s I edited the code accordingly to your comment